# Inverse Kronecker product or minimize a distance norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, kronecker-product, transition-matrix

Let $A$ be a real valued $4n \times 4n$ matrix, $B$ is a real valued $4\times4$ matrix, and $C$ is a non-negative $n\times n$ matrix. I have $A$ and $B$ and I am trying to get $C$ through this equation: 
$$
A = C \otimes B
$$

The elements of $C$ have a certain structure:

Consider the following transition probability matrix $Q$ where
$$
Q_{i,j} =  \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
      1-p-q & \text{if } j=i-1 \\
      p     & \text{if } j=i\\
      q     &  \text{if } j=i+1\\
\end{array} 
\right. 
$$

Then the elements of $C$ will be $(C_{k,l}) = [Q^l]_{1,k+1}$ where $Q^l$ is the $l$-step transition matrix.

I was thinking two things: (1) get $C$ by doing some sort of inverse kronecker product or (2) get $C$ by minimizing some norm $||A-C\otimes B||$ with respect to $C$. But more specifically, I want to get $p$ and $q$. Does someone have any citations I can read to help me figure it out or have any suggestions for me? Thanks.

Comment: Is $B$ invertible?

Comment: Yes, B is invertible.

Comment: @CindryLhasapoo: Then why don't you multiply $A$ by $I_{4n} \otimes B^{-1}$ and get $A(I_{4n} \otimes B^{-1}) = (C \otimes B)(I_{4n} \otimes B^{-1}) = (C I_{4n} \otimes B B^{-1}) = C \otimes I_{4}$ and get $C$ from there?